# Iterate through multiple combo boxes in a container pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt

I’m having a problem with extracting data from multiple comboboxes at once. I have around 10 comboboxes in a container. I could extract the data individual but that would result in repeated code.
This is what I have so far but doesn’t seem to work at all:

```
  def extractData():
     window.survey= window.surveyContainer.currentText()
  for results in window.surveryContainer.children():    
     results.currentTextChanged.connect(extractData)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you will need to have all the comboboxes you want to access on the same container (in this case I assume it is `surveryContainer`), then you can do:

```py
for results in window.surveryContainer.findChildren(QComboBox):    
   results.currentTextChanged.connect(extractData)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried this and I get an error because of the extractData function. It says that Qwidget has no attribute to currentText.

Comment: well that's a different issue, what it means essentially is that Qwidget doesn't have this method (currentText). Here's the documentation with available methods for solving that second issue: https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QWidget.html. If I answered the first question of accessing comboboxes in a loop, please consider marking it as solved.

Comment: I had a look through the documentation for a while but I’m still unsure what method could replace currentText. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: I'm afraid I can't be of much help as I'm not that proficient in PyQt's QWidget to know what the problem is.. It would be better to make a separate post about the currentText method problem I believe

Comment: No worries. Your help till now is really appreciated! Thank you!